# How does one write extension methods similar to the ones provided for Dependency injection? Eg: .AddTransient<IOperationTransient, Operation>()?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

**Writing extension methods is quite simple in C#. For Eg:**

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static int WordCount(this String str)
    {
        return str.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?' },
                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
    }
}
```

**This is how you could use it:**

```
string s = "Hello Extension Methods";
int i = s.WordCount();
```

But extension methods that are provided by .NET Core for dependency injection seems to be different in how you use them.  Eg: `services.AddTransient<IOperationTransient, Operation>()`

**Typical way to register a dependency is :**

```
var item = new ServiceDescriptor(
           typeof(IoperationTransient),
           a=> new Operaton(),
           ServiceLifetime.Transient
           );
           services.Add(item);
```

**Short-hand provided by .NET Core:**

```
services.AddTransient<IOperationTransient, Operation>();
```

**I tried to recreate AddTransient method by creating an extension method using this code:**

```
    public static void AddTransientCustom<T1,T2>(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var item = new ServiceDescriptor(
             typeof(T1),
             a => Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T2)),
             ServiceLifetime.Transient
             );
        services.Add(item);
    }
```

**Then I used it as following in the ConfigureServices method:**

```
services.AddTransientCustom<IOperationTransient, Operation>();
```

But it does not work. I get an error telling me that IOperationTransient could not be resolved in the controller.

I am not trying to re-invent the wheel. I am just curious and would like to know it for knowledge.

Comment: .NET Core/5 is open source. You can look at its implementation.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/src/ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.cs

Comment: @Crowcoder That was the first thing I tried. I went to https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore  --> Go to File --> IServiceCollection  but I could not find anything relevant.  There was a "ServiceCollectionExtensions" class but that doesn't seem to be what I am looking for.  I think I need to work on my skill to explore public github code base.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/0605bb3aba533702f234c907906ef076a97131fe/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/src/ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.cs#L667) is the line you are looking for.

Comment: https://source.dot.net might be more useful as it offers code navigation. https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.cs,ec3df16f59c7c607

Comment: @abdusco I never knew they have something like this. It IS more useful. However I am looking that function right now and then comparing it with my extension method , I am not able to figure out what is different? In official code, I am looking at lines 135==>110==>24==>44 calling `Add(services, serviceType, implementationType, ServiceLifetime.Transient);` ==>
     650 creating an instance of ServiceDescriptor class by passing three params (Type,Type,ServiceLifetime). Isn't that what I am doing in my extention method?

Comment: I think your mistake is in this line `a => Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T2))`. Why do you provide implementation factory instead of just providing the type? Why  do you think `T2` has default constructor and can be created without providing constructor arguments to `Activator`? Instead of registering implementation factory just register implementation type: `new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(T1), typeof(T2), ServiceLifetime.Transient);`

Comment: @Artur you are right. Thank you for pointing that out. It was silly of me. Thank you. I now know what I wanted to know. Thanks again.